# What is an adjective meaning "informing others"?

Tags: word-request, collocations

In translations, sometimes several parts of the source texts are completely deleted.
 This happens either with prior notice (e.g. it is stated clearly in the preface that several chapters have not been translated) or without any mention of it.

I call the latter "**stealthy deletions**". I am looking for a similar friend for the former, those done with prior notice. What do you suggest? Especially, I am interested in a word that has the element of *informing others* in it.

Is "**overt deletions**" good?

Comment: Yes, "Overt" and "Covert" would work perfectly here.

Comment: You mean you're looking for a word that can describe this has been done **without informing anyone**?  What's wrong with the one you use, **without prior notice**?

Comment: I can think of many synonyms for *deletion* (*elision, redaction, omission, elimination*), but none that have, built into their meaning, the sense of something purposeful. (Unless you consider **paraphrase** to fulfill that role?) If you're looking for synonymous adjectives: *deliberate, intentional, obvious, informed, signalled, notified* . . .)

Comment: @Andrew I am looking for an adjective to use it in a heading.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the term *prior notice* for that, personally, because that feels to me like something that you would use to describe the publishing process - where the translator turned in their work and it had sections missing.

***[Covert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/covert)*** and ***[overt](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overt)*** are absolutely appropriate here.